# Unable to start firefox on centOs 6 from iterm2 on mac

Tags: centos, ssh, firefox, timeout, iterm2

I have installed firefox and xauth on the centOs 6.6 server as follows:

```
sudo yum install firefox
sudo yum install xauth
```

On my mac, I am using iTerm2 
On my iTerm2 session, I also exported my display as follows:

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.0.3:0.0
```

Then from my iTerm2 session I ssh to this centOs 6.6 server as follows:

```
ssh -Y server
```

Then in my centOs 6.6 server I try to start firefox as follows:

```
firefox&
```

Then I get after a long time the connection timed out error as follows:

```
$ firefox&
[1] 56352
$ connect 192.168.0.3 port 6000: Operation timed out
```

Can someone please help me fix this so that I can start firefox on centOs 6.6 using from iTerm2 on mac using ssh?

Comment: Do you have X11 running on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Able to open firefox now. 
**But it is extremely slow** 
Anything I type in URL, it shows getting typed after big lag. 
Same is for any form input values. 
I wanted to use it for automation suite. 
So probably its useless for any practical purpose.

Following steps worked for me:

1) On centOs server:

```
sudo yum install firefox
sudo yum install xauth
```

2) On Mac - installed XQuartz and opened its terminal. 
Basically followed this link https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=280461906

**Did not export DISPLAY this time on xterm on mac.**

3) xhost +

4) ssh into the centos server from the xterm (from quartz) not iterm2:

```
ssh -Y server
```

5) Started firefox in centos from xterm:

```
firefox&
```